# Spring Configuration Metadata

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am setting up two data sources as shown here at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources using spring boot, but when doing so my `application.properties` shows warnings that for example `x.x.username` is an unknown property.  This is correct to some extent as `javax.sql.DataSource` does not contain url, username, password, etc. but the implementation classes do.  I have annotation processor set up and it works fine when working with concrete classes.

I notice that `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration` uses both `DataSourceProperties` and has `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated on `dataSource()`.  This would probably get rid of my warnings but what is the point of this.  Isn't it setting the properties twice this way?

Config:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.primary")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.secondary")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

Properties with warnings:

```
datasource.primary.url=jdbc:...
datasource.primary.username=user
datasource.primary.password=password

datasource.secondary.url=jdbc:...
datasource.secondary.username=user
datasource.secondary.password=password
```

Comment: Could you please add some code for your configuration? Where does the warning pop up? Compile time vs. Runtime? Is the application working correctly even with the warnings?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I left that out.  The warning is an editor warning in STS.  They have a special editor for spring boot properties files.  I simply get yellow underlines on those properties because the annotation processor is generating a META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json file that says it should look at javax.sql.DataSource.  I will add my config above and some of the properties with warnings.  This question really involves Spring Tool Suite, Spring Boot, and @ConfigurationProperties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since someone bothered to +1 this question I thought I'd post a solution.  Note that I think the `@ConfigurationProperties` on the `DataSource`s themselves are unecessary because they are already set on the `DataSourceProperties` which is used to build the `DataSource`, but I left it in there because that's how the Spring team has done it in `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration`.  My only guess why would be if your `DataSource` had additional properties that could be set other than what's exposed in `DataSourceProperties`, but then you would get warnings in the "Spring Boot application.properties editor" for those properties.

Note that `DataSourceBuilder` will use Tomcat, HikariCP or Commons DBCP in that order if found on Classpath as `DataSource` unless you specify something else with `dataSourceBuilder.type(Class<? extends DataSource>)`

Properties:

```
datasource.primary.url=jdbc:...
datasource.primary.username=user
datasource.primary.password=password

datasource.secondary.url=jdbc:...
datasource.secondary.username=user
datasource.secondary.password=password
```

Java Config:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.primary")
public DataSourceProperties primaryProps() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.secondary")
public DataSourceProperties secondaryProps() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.primary")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    DataSourceProperties props = secondaryProps();
    return DataSourceBuilder.create(props.getClassLoader())
            .driverClassName(props.getDriverClassName())
            .url(props.getUrl())
            .username(props.getUsername())
            .password(props.getPassword())
            .build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.primary")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    DataSourceProperties props = secondaryProps();
    return DataSourceBuilder.create(props.getClassLoader())
            .driverClassName(props.getDriverClassName())
            .url(props.getUrl())
            .username(props.getUsername())
            .password(props.getPassword())
            .build();
}
```